# HTML5/Javascript Progress multiple animated bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modernizr

I've tried many things, but none of them turned out correctly...

I am trying to animate an HTML5/Javascript Progress bar, and have multiple of these in one page. Also, I am trying to keep everything in one HTML file using `<style>` and `<script>` tags.

Now, here's my problem: The bar part of the progress bar doesn't show up on any progress bars after the first one [[See here/JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JonaK/S9PQr/3/)] [[Where I got the code from](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/)]

```
 <body>
    <div class="demo-wrapper html5-progress-bar"> <!-- This one shows just fine -->
        <div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
            <progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100" stop="57"></progress>    <span class="progress-value">0%</span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="demo-wrapper html5-progress-bar"> <!-- This one? Not so much. -->
        <div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
            <progress id="progressbar2" value="0" max="100" stop="57"></progress>   <span class="progress-value">0%</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: each bar should have a different id

Comment: Did that, didn't help. Although, I really should have done that in the first place...

Comment: Did you modify your JavaScript function to create a variable for each id? The way your code is set up you create a variable based on $("#progressbar") so you need to do this for each bar and set up a progress bar in jquery for each id.

Comment: Ah. That fixed it. Thanks! I'm a little new to HTML/Javascript. You might want to post this as an answer for other people that had my problem

Comment: You only use progressbar2 once in your jsFiddle. Where is the part of the code that is animating progressbar2? Can you give me a quick walkthrough, with line numbers? Nvr mind - somebody beat me to it :)

Comment: this fiddle is kinda confusing

Comment: @RobertKotcher : I just updated my fiddle. [[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/JonaK/S9PQr/3/)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your progress bars have the same id, they should each have a distinct `id` ie: `progressbar1`, `progressbar2`. Then you need to modify your JavaScript code to build a progress bar for each id.

Answer (score 1):

The progressbars have the same id so the compiler treats the two progressbars as the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Didn't change anything. That was a stupid mistake on my part though

Comment: He also needs to modify his script to account for the different id's